# What is the difference between jQuery's space and > selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

What's the difference between the [space](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/descendant#ancestordescendant) and [>](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child) selectors? And possibly related, how can I look for something that's the direct child of something else, and not lower down the descendant line?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 2.1</li>
      <li>Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

For example

```
$("ul > li").addClass("blah");
```

adds class "blah" to 1 2 and 3 whereas:

```
$("ul li").addClass("blah");
```

add class "blah" to every list element.

I'm not sure what you're referring to with < and ? operators.

Comment: Does ul > li set all of them to "blah"?  because you have a sub list which also has li children in a ul.

Comment: > means immediate children, not grandchildren or more.

Comment: ul > li matches the nested lists as well

Comment: You should update your example to have the inner `ul` as an `ol` since your current code will not function as you describe (though technically correct).

Answer (score 10):

In CSS, `>` means "direct child of": only nodes that are direct children are selected.

While a space means "any descendant of": direct children and children of those children could be selected.

I would wager jQuery uses the same convention.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, a space will select any descendant, whereas `>` will select only immediate children. If you want to select only grandchildren or great-grandchildren, then you could use this:

```
#foo > * > * > .bar
```

(all elements with class "bar" which are great grandchildren of the element with id "foo")

Answer (score 2):

look at this..

```
$(".testit > a") //match the first <a> tag below
$(".testit a") // matches all <a> tag below

<p class="testit">
  <a href="#">All the rules will match this</a>
  <span>
    <a href="#">second rule can only select this</a>
  </span>
</p>
```