# binding jquery to dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery

I have the following html tree :

```
<div class="section yellow" id="section1">
    <div id="content-wrap1" class="content-wrap">
</div>
```

I am using ajax to load the following content into `#content-wrap1`:

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="whoweare.php">Who we are</a>
    <a href="whatwedo.php">Our team</a>
    <p>ABOUT US : Dance is a type of art</p>
</div>
```

which happens successfully, and the resulting HTML looks like this :

```
<div class="section yellow" id="section1">
    <div id="content-wrap1" class="content-wrap">.
        <div id="content">
        <a href="whoweare.php">Who we are</a>
        <a href="whatwedo.php">Our team</a>
        <p>ABOUT US : Dance is a type of art</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to click on the dynamically loaded link to load the following content :

```
<div id="content">
    <a href="whoweare.php">Who we are</a>
    <a href="whatwedo.php">Our team</a>
    <p>Hi there! How are you?</p>
</div>
```

so that the final HTML looks like this :

```
<div class="section yellow" id="section1">
    <div id="content-wrap1" class="content-wrap">.
        <div id="content">
        <a href="whoweare.php">Who we are</a>
        <a href="whatwedo.php">Our team</a>
        <p>Hi there! How are you?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have heard that I should use `on()` to bind jquery to a dynamically loaded content. So I do the following:

```
('#section1').on("click", "#section1#content-wrap1#content a", function(){
    alert("1");
    toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('content-wrap1').load(toLoad);
}
```

**Ques1**: Is this the correct usage of `on()` ? Because when I click the link, I don't get `alert 1` on the screen and the page simply navigates to `whoweare.php`

**Ques2**: Incase I do manage to get the alert, is it possible theoritically to click on a link that loads content that replaces the link clicked in the first place ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Ques1:** Is this the correct usage of on() ? Because when I click the link, I don't get alert 1 on the screen and the page simply navigates to whoweare.php

- you are missing a dollar sign: `$` and use `document` you are binding same id on same id which is not correct, further if you keen: [What is the meaning of "$" sign in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript) & If you are more keen to know why `.on` [What's wrong with the jQuery live method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926)

**Code**

```
$(document).on("click", "#content a", function(){
        alert("1");
        toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('content-wrap1').load(toLoad);
})
```

**Ques2:** Incase I do manage to get the alert, is it possible theoritically to click on a link that loads content that replaces the link clicked in the first place ?

- this might help you out: [jQuery how to replace src url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127482/jquery-how-to-replace-src-url)

Comment: +1, Good answer bro, please fix this selector `#section1#content-wrap1#content a`.

Comment: What's wrong with `#section1#content-wrap1#content a` as the selector?

Comment: @soundswaste see post above i.e. from  techfoobar, further take a look in here: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ **also see in here** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218068/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-space-and-selectors `:)`

Comment: Oh btw, I read somewhere its performance-wise better if I use the nearest parent ID (like `$('#section1')` instead of `$(document)`. Thoughts?

Comment: @soundswaste No Worried `:))` GLad it helped! no sure whta will the exact JPref numbers but one advantage of using `document` is that you can be relaxed about using new dynamic elements getting added anywhere in the DOM and `.on` will take care of it, let me know where you read about this, `:)`

Answer (score 2):

**Ques 1**

Your bind statement should be like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#section1 #content-wrap1 #content a", function() {
    ...
});
```

Notice that we are now binding to the `document` object to accomodate any and all elements matching the second selector (`#section1 #content-wrap1 #content a`) loaded dynamically or otherwise.

Also, notice the correction in the second selector (spaces).

**Ques 2**

*is it possible theoritically to click on a link that loads content that replaces the link clicked in the first place ?*

**Yes. Totally.**