# Jquery working when li is on top, not when it is on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've designed a program. With it i can move li tags on my page.

Code:

```js
var click = 0;
var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;
var a = 0;
var out = [0, 0, 0, 0];

$(".movenode").mousedown(function() {
    a = $(this).attr("id");
        var b = $(this).position();
        if(click == 0)
        {
            pos_x = b.left;
            pox_y = b.top;
        }
        click = 1;
        
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(click==1) {
            $("#"+a).css({left:e.pageX-b.left-40, top:e.pageY-b.top-10});
        }
   });
    
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   $("#"+a).css({left:pos_x, top:pos_y});
    var d = 1;
    while(d < 5) {
        var pos = $("#"+d).position();
        if(e.pageY > pos.top && e.pageY < pos.top + $("#"+d).height() && e.pageX > pos.left && e.pageX < pos.left + $("#"+d).width()) {
        alert($("#"+d).attr("id"));
        }
        d++;
    }

    click = 0;
});
```

```css
.movenode {
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="movenode" id="1"/>1234
<li class="movenode" id="2"/>sadsdsadsad
<li class="movenode" id="3"/>sadsdsadsad
<li class="movenode" id="4"/>sadsdsadsad
```

This code works. But i have a little problem. When i add this code to my html file and set the elements in this order:

1. HTML (just this 4 li)
2. LOAD CSS TO html
3. Load JS to html

This program works, but when I set this elements in this order:

1. Load css to html
2. Load js to html
3. HTML (this 4 li)

this program doeasn't work. I cannot move this li. In fact, JS works because shows me alerts, but still i cannot move this li.
I cannot us head, body etc. because its not working.
What should i do to repair this bug?

Comment: This is like loading HTML dynamically. You have to use the .on() function of jQuery like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107715/binding-jquery-to-dynamically-loaded-content

Comment: first of all your should be careful to load js code before close body tag and ,then you should wrap all js code in $(document).ready() function

Comment: when you work with the DOM like this, in javascript or jQuery, the html elements must exist for the browser, if this js code is placed before, the html elements are not parsed yet, and selection fails. You must either place it after (usually right after the elements, or at the very end of the body), or use `$(document).ready` by the way your code causes strange displays here (firefox)

Comment: note: your li tags are not closed, and have no ul, poor of them

Comment: Oh, ok guys, thanks vary much, working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding  `$(document).ready(function(){ //code });`

```js
var click = 0;
var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;
var a = 0;
var out = [0, 0, 0, 0];
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".movenode").mousedown(function() {
    a = $(this).attr("id");
        var b = $(this).position();
        if(click == 0)
        {
          pos_x = b.left;
          pox_y = b.top;
        }
        click = 1;
        
        $(document).mousemove(function(e) 
        {
          if(click==1)
          {
           $("#"+a).css({left:e.pageX-b.left-40, top:e.pageY-b.top-10});
          }
     });
    
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
   $("#"+a).css({left:pos_x, top:pos_y});
 var d = 1;
while(d < 5)
{
    var pos = $("#"+d).position();

  if(e.pageY > pos.top && e.pageY < pos.top + $("#"+d).height() && e.pageX > pos.left && e.pageX < pos.left + $("#"+d).width())
    {
        alert($("#"+d).attr("id"));
    }
    d++;
}

   
     click = 0;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="movenode" id="1"/>1234
<li class="movenode" id="2"/>sadsdsadsad
<li class="movenode" id="3"/>sadsdsadsad
<li class="movenode" id="4"/>sadsdsadsad
```

Comment: thanks, i don't know when i forgot about it. Now all is working, thank you :)